# Why is this update query throwing a syntax error?

Tags: mysql

Here is my update string. I cannot figure out what the syntax error is even though it is a pretty simple query.

```
UPDATE building SET building_name='1901' building_lead_user='29' building_maint_user='23' WHERE building_id='4' LIMIT 1
```

building

```
Field   Type    Allow Null  Default Value
building_id int(6)  No  
building_name   varchar(30) Yes 
building_lead_user  int(6)  Yes 
building_maint_user int(6)  Yes 
status  int(1) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL    Yes
```

Comment: You are missing commas between the update definitions...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing commas to separate the fields you're updating:

```
UPDATE building SET building_name='1901', building_lead_user='29', building_maint_user='23' WHERE building_id='4' LIMIT 1
```